# Android: moving image on screen

Tags: android, image

What I want to achieve with this program is , when my finger is touching the image and I am moving(dragging) it on the screen , the image should move along , and as soon as I release my finger , the image should remain at the last touched position. But my image keeps moving on the screen from first touched position to last touched position as the loop keeps updating, giving me this effect.

[image]

Here is MainGamePanel class which draws image on screen:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;
private Droid droid;

public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder() , this);
    droid = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 50, 50);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry)
    {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        droid.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        if(event.getY() > getHeight() - 50)
        {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cords: x = "+event.getX()+" ,y = "+event.getY());
        }
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        if(droid.isTouched())
        {
            droid.setX((int)event.getX());
            droid.setY((int)event.getY());
        }
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        if(droid.isTouched())
        {
            droid.setTouched(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    droid.draw(canvas);
}

}
```

And here is the handleActionDown method of Droid class:

```
public void handleActionDown(int eventX, int eventY)
{
    if(eventX >=(x - bitmap.getWidth()/2) && (eventX <= x + (bitmap.getWidth()/2)))
    {
        if(eventY >=(y - bitmap.getHeight()/2) && (y <= y + (bitmap.getHeight()/2)))
        {
            setTouched(true);
        }else
        {
            setTouched(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setTouched(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to clear the canvas before drawing the image.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    //Just call this line
    canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1,mBitmap1Point.x-(mBitmap1.getWidth()/2),mBitmap1Point.y-(mBitmap1.getHeight()/2),null);
}
```

Worked fine for me.